# Dump roles on AWS without pg_dumpall -g access (postgresql 9.6.8)?

Tags: postgresql-9.6, aws-aurora

We have a system on AWS RDS Aurora, PostgreSQL v 9.6.8 option.

We are trying to move its roles to a new encrypted 10.5 instance, but we don't have superuser access that's required to do pg_dumpall -g on the old instance. (I am aware of the update to Postgres 10.0 that lets you do this without superuser access, but this is 9.6.8).

Any ideas for a workaround? Thanks in advance for any suggestions whatsoever!

Answer (score 4):

It turns out the 10.0 solution was backported (apparently) to 9.6.8, so:

```
pg_dumpall --host <aws_endpoint> --globals-only --no-role-passwords \
    --username masteruser >roles.sql
```

Then run *roles.sql* against the new database.

Comment: Verified with version 9.6.18 and got the following error `pg_dumpall: unrecognized option '--no-role-passwords'`. Looks like it's unsupported.

Comment: Use pg_dumpall utility of newer version like 10 or 12, it is working then.